# How to draw this checkbox icon using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, math, geometry, uibezierpath

I am working on creating some custom buttons for an app, there are several icons, and I have designed them all in theory, but I'm having trouble with figuring out how to draw this pesky "checkbox" icon in iOS' UIBezierPath language.

As a general rule, the bounds of the icon are 5 x 5, and the bounds of the graphic contained inside the icon is 3 x 3. (Yes, I know that the checkbox protrudes outside the 3 x 3 bounds).

Here is both a checkbox icon, and a "plus sign" icon (Yes, I ball with Corel DRAW 12, so what...):

[image]

You see, the "plus" icon, I could do no problem like this:

```
class BezierPathFactory {


    // "gridSpacing" is expected to be the containing view's width / 5
    static func plus(gridSpacing G: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x:2*G,y:G)

        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:2*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G,y:2*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G,y:3*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:3*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:4*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:4*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:3*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:3*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:2*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:2*G))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:G))
        path.addLine(to: startPoint)

        path.close()

        return path

}

// ...

}
```

But, the checkbox icon makes my head hurt so bad.

I have ascertained the following things so far:

1. The length: width ratio (rotated 45 degrees clockwise) of the checkmark is 4: 2
2. The CGPoint of the upper right corner of the checkmark is identical to the upper right corner of the "inside (3 x 3) box"
3. If the grid spacing of the icon is 1, then from a 45 degree perspective, each "block" of the checkmark is ( sqrt(18) / 5 ) high and/or wide.

Any mathematicians in the house?

I'm still working on it but feel free to give it an attempt.

This is what I have thus far:

```
static func checkMark(gridSpacing G: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {


        let blurp = UIBezierPath()

        let CM_hyp = sqrt((18*G)/5)

        let CM_opp_or_adj = sqrt( ((CM_hyp)*(CM_hyp)) / 2 )

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 4*G, y: G)

        blurp.move(to: startPoint)
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (4*G)+CM_opp_or_adj, y: G + CM_opp_or_adj))
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 4*G-(3*CM_opp_or_adj), y: 4*G) )
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: G, y:(4*G) - 2*CM_opp_or_adj ))
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: G + CM_opp_or_adj, y: (2*G) + CM_opp_or_adj) )
        //6
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: 2*G + CM_opp_or_adj, y:      (4*G) - 2*CM_opp_or_adj   )     )
        blurp.addLine(to: startPoint)


        blurp.close()


        return blurp

    }
```

But it looks goofy. I did something wrong.

Comment: I think you can just add 2 lines with 90 degrees arc and increase the width instead of drawing....everything?

Comment: negative!!!! :)

Comment: I'd recommend [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com)

Comment: I would draw a backwards L and rotate it. Isn't this what we just learned to do in your other question???

Comment: PaintCode is the best, but if you want to do it manually, I do a scale of 0,0 -> 1,1, so the points scale to any size but then you can do easy math from a raster graphic. Say a point is at 43,33 in a 100x100 image, so you add a point @ (width *.43, height * .33)

Comment: oh no not the downvotes! I know this sounds like homework, but it ain't.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think this is a bad question. I don't know what “grid unit length” is. I don't know what the relationship between the thickness of the checkmark and the grid spacing is. Only one of the six vertices of the checkmark is on a grid point, but I have no idea why the others are off the grid points or how far off they are. There is a good tool for this, PaintCode, which @MadProgrammer linked you to. Maybe Corel can give you the exact vertex coordinates. Maybe you can export to SVG or another human-readable format.

Comment: @matt That could probably be done, but since the checkmark's bounds aren't square we have that "where is the center" issue.  I suppose there could be a way to trick it into being symetrical like adding white space on one end... but I consulted Pythagoras this time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that program a while back and I remember getting frustrated bcause it doesn't export paths/code in any "relative" format... as in... the points are absolute.  I need the paths to automatically draw at the correct size even if the view size is unknown.

Comment: @BooberBunz Raise a feature request

Comment: @BooberBunz that sounds like a problem with your understanding of Paintcode. It is certainly possible to output relatively sized code. You just need to make sure that you tell it that’s what you want. I have used it to create all the icons and artwork in an app before and creating them at the right size and scale depending on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I got it working...

It was basically a bunch of math errors and Bacardi to blame.

```
static func checkMark(gridSpacing G: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {        

        let blurp = UIBezierPath()

        let CM_hyp = ((sqrt(18))/5) * G

        let CM_opp_or_adj = sqrt( ((CM_hyp)*(CM_hyp)) / 2 )

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 4*G, y: G)

        blurp.move(to: startPoint)
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (4*G)+CM_opp_or_adj, y: G + CM_opp_or_adj))
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (4*G)-(3*CM_opp_or_adj), y: 4*G) )
        //3
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: G, y:(4*G) - 2*CM_opp_or_adj ))

        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: G + CM_opp_or_adj, y: (4*G) - 3*CM_opp_or_adj ) )
        blurp.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: (4*G)-(3*CM_opp_or_adj), y: (4*G) - 2*CM_opp_or_adj ) )
        blurp.addLine(to: startPoint)

        blurp.close()
        // !!
        return blurp

    }

static func checkMarkBox(gridSpacing G: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

        let boxPath = UIBezierPath()

        boxPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:G, y: G))
        boxPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G, y: G))
        boxPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G, y: 4*G))
        boxPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G, y: 4*G))
        boxPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G, y: G))

        boxPath.close()

        return boxPath

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a custom checkBox as the button

```
@IBDesignable class SquareCheckBox: UIButton {
//MARK: - Properties
@IBInspectable var isOn:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
//gives the actual functionality of the button


@IBInspectable var tickWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
//decides the width of the tick
/*
 THIS VALUE CANNOT EXCEED THE HALF OF THE BUTTON'S HEIGHT OR GO BELOW ZERO. IT WILL RESET TO 3.0 IN ANY SUCH CASE.
 */


@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 3.0
//decides the width of the border of the button
/*
 THIS VALUE WILL BE RESET TO 3.0 IF THE DEVELOPER EXCEEDS THE 1/4TH OF THE BUTTON'S HEIGHT OR BELOW ZERO.
 */


@IBInspectable var borderRadius: CGFloat = 3.0
//decides the corner radius of the button
/*
 THIS VALUE CANNOT EXCEED THE HALF OF THE BUTTON'S HEIGHT OR GO BELOW ZERO. IT WILL RESET TO 3.0 IN ANY SUCH CASE.
 */


@IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
//decides the color of the border of the button


@IBInspectable public var BGColorOn: UIColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
//decides the color of button's background when it is checked


@IBInspectable public var BGColorOff: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
//decides the color of button's background when it is checked


@IBInspectable public var tickColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
//decides the color of the tick

//MARK: - Overriden Functions
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
    //removing any title as it doesn't allow the layers in button to form and crashes the App
}
// Xcode uses this to render the button in the storyboard.


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
// The storyboard loader uses this at runtime.


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let boxDim = min(bounds.height, bounds.width)
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor


    //NOTE: we cannot set the value for the radius more than half of the width if the width is smaller than height OR we cannot set the value for the radius more than half of the width if the height is smaller than the width
    if borderRadius < 0 || borderRadius > boxDim/2 {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    } else {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.borderRadius
    }

    //creating box
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: self.borderRadius)
    //creating tick
    let tickPath = UIBezierPath()

    tickPath.lineWidth = 2.0

    //tick's path
    if bounds.width > bounds.height{
        //when width is greater than height
        tickPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 - boxDim/3, y: boxDim/2))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 - boxDim/6, y: ((boxDim)*3)/4))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 + boxDim/3, y: boxDim/4))
    } else if bounds.width < bounds.height{
        //when height is greater than width
        tickPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: boxDim/6, y: bounds.height/2))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((boxDim)*2)/6, y: (((boxDim)*3)/4) - boxDim/2 + bounds.height/2))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((boxDim)*5)/6, y: bounds.height/2 - (boxDim/4)))
    } else {
        //when it's a square
        tickPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: boxDim/6, y: boxDim/2))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((boxDim)*2)/6, y: ((boxDim)*3)/4))
        tickPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((boxDim)*5)/6, y: boxDim/4))
    }



    if isOn{
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        BGColorOn.setFill()//setting background color for when box is on
        path.fill()

        //creating sublayer
        let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer.frame = self.bounds
        pathLayer.path = tickPath.cgPath
        pathLayer.strokeColor = tickColor.cgColor//setting tick color
        pathLayer.fillColor = nil
        //NOTE: we cannot set the value for the width of tick more than one-fourth of width if width is smaller than height OR we cannot set the value for the width of tick more than one-fourth of width if height is smaller than width
        //we cannot set the value for the width of tick less than one
        if tickWidth < 1 || tickWidth > boxDim/4 {
            pathLayer.lineWidth = 2
        }else {
            pathLayer.lineWidth = tickWidth
        }

        pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

        //adding sublayer
        self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)

        //animating
        let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        pathAnimation.duration = 0.5
        pathAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        pathAnimation.toValue = 1.0
        pathLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    } else {
        if borderWidth < 0 || borderWidth > boxDim/4 {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        } else {
            self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        }
        BGColorOff.setFill()
        path.fill()
        self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        //removing all sublayers
    }
}
}
```

it's got various properties which you can tweak with by creating an instance of this class

Comment: Thanks for the demo... I also have a custom class but it has an inspectable type: Int variable that controls what the icon is... there are many of them... kindof like a calculator... in the draw()  method it fetches from static methods in my UIBezierPathFactory class.  Your way is probably btter but I'm going with this for now.  Also posted my own answer... I need the checkmark to be 'just so' because I am rigidly meticulous.